# Create an adjacency from dataframe with two columns with R

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataframe that has this structure

```
ID LINEITEM
1  shirt1
1  shirt2
2  shirt1
3  shirt3
3  shirt4
4  shirt5
5  shirt1
5  shirt2
5  shirt6
```

How can I shape the data in order to create edges and nodes between the LINEITEMS according to how many times they appear on the same ID?

My expected output would be:

```
       Shirt1 Shirt2 Shirt3 Shirt4 Shirt5 Shirt6
Shirt1   0      2       0       0      0       1   
Shirt2   2      0       0       0      0       0   
Shirt3   0      0       0       1      0       0   
Shirt4   0      0       1       0      0       0   
Shirt5   0      0       0       0      0       0   
Shirt6   1      1       0       0      0       0
```

which counts every time two shirts appear on a same ID together)

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen added!

Answer (score 3):

Check with `table`

```
table(df$ID, df$LINEITEM)
```

As r2evans mentioned in comments

```
xtabs(~ ID + LINEITEM, data = df)
```

Comment: Similarly, `xtabs(~ ID + LINEITEM, data = df)`

Comment: @r2evans would you mind I adding that :-)

Comment: Feel free to add it, they go together (the biggest difference I find is that `xtabs` goes beyond two dims, but sometimes `table` is sufficient for me).